# Change UITableViewCell background color in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I use a list to display a dynamic number of custom views. See code.

```
 @State var coins : [Coin]
```

```
var coinList : some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<coins.count, id: \.self) { i in
                    CoinEntry(coin: coins[i])
                }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    self.coins.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                })
        }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    }
```

After that, I had this list.

[image]

After that I modified the list like this.

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

The bottom of the list has now changed to clear, but the cells are still white.

[image]

If I edit it like this:

```
CoinEntry(coin: coins[i]).background(MAIN_DARK_GRAY)
```

The list looks like this:

[image]

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Use `listRowBackground()` instead of background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change background color of a view by simply adding .background property

```
var coinList : some View {
    List {
        ForEach(0..<coins.count, id: \.self) { i in
                CoinEntry(coin: coins[i]).background(MAIN_DARK_GRAY)
            }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                self.coins.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            })
    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).background(MAIN_DARK_GRAY)
}
```

Or you can use listRowBackground property

```
var coinList : some View {
    List {
        ForEach(0..<coins.count, id: \.self) { i in
                CoinEntry(coin: coins[i])
            }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                self.coins.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
            })
    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).listRowBackground(MAIN_DARK_GRAY)
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question accordingly, even if I drag the `CoinView()` to the entire length of the screen, I still have white border on top and bottom and front.